# How to express numbers between 1 and 1000 as a sum of consecutive integers in two different ways

Tags: number-theory

How many integers 1≤N≤1000 can be written both as the sum of 26 consecutive integers and as the sum of 13 consecutive integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution presented by [Eric](https://brilliant.org/profile/eric-4wqh3r/). Note that we feature solutions from students the week after the problems are released.

Suppose that $x$ can be expressed as the sum of 26 consecutive integers and 13 consecutive integers. Let the 13 integers be $a - 6, a - 5, ..., a + 5, a + 6$. Then $x = 13a$.

Let the 26 consecutive integers be $b - 12, b - 11, ..., b + 12, b + 13$. Then $x = 26b + 13$. Thus, $x = 0 \pmod{13}$, and $x = 13 \pmod{26}$.

Thus, the values of $x$ that work are $13(2n + 1)$ for nonnegative integers $n$. It is well-known that $1001 = 7*11*13$, so the largest value of $x$ that works is $13(77 - 2) = 13*75$. Thus, the values of $x$ that work are $13*1, 13*3, ..., 13*75$, so 38 numbers work, Q. E. D.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If $a$ is the first term of the [AP series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Derivation) with $13$ members, the sum will be $$\frac{13}2\cdot \{2\cdot a+(13-1)1\}=13(a+6)$$ as the common difference $=1$ here.

Similarly, for $26$ consecutive integers, the sum will be $$\frac{26}2\cdot \{2\cdot b+(26-1)1\}=13(2b+25)$$

We need  $$13(a+6)=13(2b+25)\iff a+6=2b+25\implies a=2b+19$$

and  to check $$1\le 13(a+6)\le 1000 $$

$$\implies 1\le 13(2b+25)\le 1000\implies 1\le 2b+25\le 76\implies -12\le b\le 25$$

Comment: sir, that is not what i asked could you take another look please.

Comment: @Shobhit You asked two questions. The one in the title and the one on the question's body do not match.

Comment: @Shobhit, could you please clarify the  question in the title?

Comment: i am sorry about the title sir consider it absurd, please focus on the question thank you.

Comment: @Shobhit, have you checked the answer?

Comment: yes sir, it is wrong. could you be  more specific

Comment: This is a live problem on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/i/Q4fWBT/) (link attached). Please close this. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master.